# Is it possible and practical to add a larger screen to an Android phone?

Tags: screen

I've been working on an Android navigation app, and to be able to use this on my motorcycle I need a waterproof device. Since I couldn't find a waterproof device that fits my needs, I was thinking of buying standard parts and recasing them.

Would it be possible to take a motherboard from let's say a Huawei P8 and attach a larger and brighter screen to it?

What would be some tips on doing this?

Comment: Theoretically, it's indeed possible. What is your experience regarding development of custom video drivers for Android? Which display data transfer protocols are you familiar with?

Comment: To be honest, I have no experience in those areas what so ever. That said however, I don't mind putting in the time and effort to learn this

Comment: There are hundreds of Android devices already out there. Why wouldn't you simply pick one that has the right screen size to begin with? As it stands, this question is a poor fit for this site — too broad, shopping, unclear what your requirements and constraints are. Modding questions need to demonstrate a good understanding of the device's design and focus on a specific issue.

Comment: Thjere is no reason to assume this would or wouldnt work, depends quite a bit on the hardware and the software, either may be forced to one resolution or even specific set of devices (digitizer, display, etc).  Just get a cheap tablet and hot spot it.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, I'm looking for a solution because I want to use a much brighter display than phones and tablet's use. This device needs to be used on a motorcycle, which means that it will br outdoors, sometimes in direct sunlight while the user may be wearing sunglasses. I've tried it with my oneplus 3t and at maximum brightness, its just not bright enough when in direct sunlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the device. If you get one with HDMI out you can connect it to an external screen and expect it to work.

Otherwise you have to take a very close look at the connectors and signal standards of the replacement screen *and touchscreen digitizer*. If you find one that's exactly the same but larger then it might work out of the box.

If it's not the same resolution then you will most likely have problems which require rooting the device and fiddling with its display drivers.

(I managed to get a variant of this by accident; the Asus Transformer has two almost-indistinguishable models of touchscreen digitizer, but one of them has the X coordinate flipped. This makes it very hard to safely buy as a spare part.)

Comment: If I could source one with hdmi out, would the touchscreen also work via the hdmi connection, or is this a seperate connector? I'm sorry for the rookie questions, I don't have a really broad electronics background.

Comment: It would need a second connection over USB.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier and cheaper if, instead of getting a phone/tablet and trying to change the screen, you get a board which actually uses custom boards.

For instance, you can get a Raspberry PI, attach an HDMI monitor to it, add the required sensors (e.g. GPS), flash android on the SD and use it. This may require some work to find the right sensor compatible out-of-the-box with the android distribution, but it is MUCH easier than trying to adapt the video drivers to your screen.

You'll also need a battery and some power converters, but it is still much easier than the other part (and you can fine-tune the features to your needs)

UPDATE: I was very surprised to discover that the rPI has no android official distro... ?????

Anyway in the past I used an Orange PI zero (this supports Android 4.4, but I used a classic linux distro for it). This has built-in wifi, but in order to use accelerometers or GPS you will have to tweak a bit.

[Here](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=174) someone managed to install a USB GPS, and maybe you can figure out how to attach an accelerometer to it if you really need it..

Keep in mind that the Orange PI and the Banana PI are very similar, so you can use one of the two and port the code and procedures from one to the other

Comment: The thing is that i'm also using things like WiFi, accelerometers, Bluetooth and 4g. I've been looking into boards but things like 3g or 4g connections add up really fast. Should I do this, would I need to create some sort of custom rom so android knows which pins are which sensors? I can't seem to find much information on this :/ I would prefer this method however because it would give me more control in choosing sensors. Would you have any suggestions on sourcing information?

Comment: @KennethBreugelmans in fact... rPI does not support android. I was a bit puzzled at this. :-? Anyway there are other boards, but usually it is a bit tricky to port the peripheral codes (even if I think it is easier than replacing the screen). As a last resort, get a tablet ;)

Comment: Looking at all the responses, the tablet option might be the easiest :p guess i'll have to look into screen glare protectors than :p thank's for the input tho :)

Answer (score 0):

As your problem (as stated in the comments) seems to be with the screen brightness rather than the actual screen, it may save a lot of work if you just beefed up the backlight LEDs and associated circuitry. This change may even be able to be modded onto the original phone PCB. This would save the effort of writing custom drivers, doing custom screen interfaces, etc. that accompanies changing the screen itself.